Endianness checking in go runtime for linux
There is this fragment of the function anyToSockaddr(rsa *RawSockaddrAny) (Sockaddr, error) residing in syscall_linux.go file in syscall package in the go runtime:
    case AF_INET:
    pp := (*RawSockaddrInet4)(unsafe.Pointer(rsa))
    sa := new(SockaddrInet4)
    p := (*[2]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&pp.Port))
    sa.Port = int(p[0])<<8 + int(p[1])
    sa.Addr = pp.Addr
    return sa, nil

What can be seen here is the port number gets converted from network byte order (big endian) to host byte order (little endian).
But doesn't the endianness depend on the architecture? Will this code have correct behavior on linux for ppc64 for example (which is big endian)?
Why there are no either checking for this nor different versions for different architectures?

What can be seen here is the port number gets converted from network byte order (big endian) to host byte order (little endian). It gets converted to host byte order, yes. Whether it is little- or big-endian doesn't matter.

Yes, I saw that by playing with a simple example in both cases.

You probably want to read The byte order fallacy

You just have small glitch in your reasoning ;-) When you manipulate a value of an integer type using a programming language (and even assembler / machine code), there simply is no concept of endianness in play—only the ordering of bits: from the least significant one to the most. The actual way these bits are stored is completely irrelevant.
When you do
int(p[0])<<8

you shift the whole value of type int 8 bits towards the most significant bit — making 8 zero bits appear as the least significant ones, and the 8 most significant bits drop off and get lost. The way we name this thing — "shift left", — and the way we have it in the Go's (and C's etc) syntax — <<, — stems from the fact the education of most of us is affected by "western" tradition, in which we write numbers in the way that their least significant digit is always the rightmost one, and this affected the syntax of the programming languages we've designed.
So, basically, we "shift left" because we write numbers (on paper) — including in binary form — in the way their LSB is always the rightmost, and their MSB is always the leftmost, so shifting the bits to the left is shifting them from the least significant ones to the most significant ones; what matters is this fact, not which end of an integer value has a lower address in memory (if any, as, say, CPU registers on today's CPUs do not have addresses).
To recap, the process of bitwise operations has no direct relation to how a particular H/W architecture stores the numbers in CPU registers and in memory.

Assuming you want to convert port 8080, which is 1F90 in hexadecimal.
In network byte order this would be
0x1f 0x90

So the above formula resolves to
0x1f << 8 + 0x90

which (since it's a computation internal to the CPU is in host byte order), so
0x1f00 + 0x90

and finally
0x1f90

or 8080 in host byte order, no matter how you calculate. On a 32 bit big endian machine this might be stored as 0x90 0x1f 0x00 0x00 in memory, still representing the integer 0x1f90
